# apache rule to proxy external images

Tags: apache-2.2, rewrite, proxypass

I would like to proxy images calls from external domains, for example that url:

```
https://example.com/proxy/http://externaldomain.com/image.jpg
```

Would respond the image (not a redirection).

Comment: so far I implemented it at my application level. It works, but if I can scope it outside of my app and let the webserver deal with that, it would be better i think

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule for `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.jpg -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.png -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://external.com/$1 [P]
```

OR

In `httpd.conf`:

```
ProxyPreserveHost off
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.(jpg|png))$ http://external.com/$1
```

Although I didn't checked both of the rules for now but please ensure that these two lines are uncommented in `httpd.conf`.

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

Comment: The regexp in `ProxyPassMatch` is wrong, since the `|` effectively splits the expression in half, so it will proxy the `.*\.jpg` or the `png` pattern (the latter being just three characters). Use the `^/(.*\.(jpg|png))` pattern instead. Also if name-based virtual hosts are used on the backend, the `ProxyPreserveHost` must be set to `Off`.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to make it clear that the external domain must be a variable, but the rule on .jpg and png is clever